# Sorting NSMutableArray with class objects for a peticular object in alphabetical order

Tags: iphone, sorting, nsarray

I have an array with property class objects like

```
for (int i=0; i<[eventList count]; i++) {

    NSDictionary *EventListDic=[eventList objectAtIndex:i];

    eventData.eventID=[EventListDic objectForKey:@"event_id"];
    eventData.eventsname=[EventListDic objectForKey:@"title"];

    [self.arrEventDataList addObject:eventData];
    [eventData release];

}
```

I want to sort this array for `eventData.eventsname` key in alphabetical order. I tried out with following functionality, but it is not working. Please suggest me how to do this. Thanks in advance

```
 NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"title" ascending:NO];
 NSArray *orderedArray = [self.arrEventDataList sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

I want to sort my arrEventDataList sorted by eventsname .

Comment: This his absolutely nothing to do with Xcode - if you used another IDE, that would make no difference.

Comment: Furthermore: "i tried out with NSSortDescriptor" - then show the code you tried. - "but it is not working" - well, "it's not working" is non-informative, just as if you went to the doctor and expected him to cure your problem after you only told him that "I feel sick".

Comment: NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:eventData.eventsname ascending:NO];
        NSArray *orderedArray = [listArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];i used this function.

Comment: @userXXX now format it and put it in the question, so that I can **read** it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortByName = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"eventsname"
                                                                 ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortByName];
NSArray *sortedArray = [arrEventDataList sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

You will have the sorted values. This will sort your `arrEventDataList`.

Answer (score 0):

Try This One...

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"self" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortedFloats = [eventData.eventsname sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:
                    [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
[sortDescriptor release];

// Put the two arrays into a dictionary as keys and values
NSDictionary *dictID = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:eventData.eventID  forKeys:eventData.eventsname];

// Sort the second array based on the sorted first array
sortedID = [dictID objectsForKeys:sortedFloats notFoundMarker:[NSNull null]];
```